# I am missing the "bookmarks" folders in the "open" and "save" dialog windons, in Kate under Linux Mint with Mate desktop

Tags: linux-mint, kde, mate, kate

I am in Linux Mint 21.1, with MATE 1.26.0. I have installed Kate version 21.12.3, via the system Software Manager.

When I want to open a file from the filesystem, or save a document, I miss the "bookmarks" that I have created in the Mint GUI, in the left column of the dialogue window (I only have "Computer", and my user home folder):

[image]

However, in other software I can use the bookmarks, here is an example from GIMP:

[image]

I understand this is an issue due to KDE in general, not Kate in particular, because I have seen the same thing in other software using KDE.

So, my question is: is there a way to get my 'bookmarks' in the dialog?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. For me... I solved it by doing the following:

Go into Control Panel -> QT5 Settings -> Appearance (1st Tab)

Change "Standard Dialogs" to "GTK2".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul!
I am not sure of what do you mean with "Control Panel".
If you refer to the Operating System "control panel", I am using Mint, with Mate DE, and I have no such thing. And In general, I can't find any system tool to manage QT5.

If you refer to Kate, I can't find any reference to QT5 in the Kate Settings, in particular in the "Configure Kate" window.

Thanks again for your answer anyways, it gives a good hint.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 21.1 Vera with MATE desktop.  The program the "QT5 Settings" icon is running is: /usr/bin/qt5ct

Comment: Thanks Paul, I upgraded my system, and was able to follow your directions, which solved the problem!
It took some time for me to follow your answer (my question is 1 year old!), but it worked! Thanks!